# Difference between render( ) and redirect( ) in django?

Tags: django

what is exactly the difference between render( ) and redirect( ) in django? I know redirect will send another request to the URL and render will render the template with the given context. But still something makes me not fully understand it. Maybe anyone can explain it well can help me a lot.
Do I have to first render the template before using redirect function. For eg: I have two templates `home.html` and `signin.html`.

```
def home(request):
   return render(request, 'home.html')

def logout(request):
   return redirect('signin')
```

or

without writing `def home` can I redirect to `home.html` like below

```
def logout(request):
   return redirect('signin')
```

Comment: `render()` returns content.  `redirect()` returns a redirect to another url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In django `render()` methods used for serve HTML pages using HTTP request also render backed data using context dictionary

### Ex -

```
def home(request):
   contex = {}
   return render(request, 'home.html',context)
```

Here `home()` function `return` `render()` method it's means it is surve `home.html` page. you can pass data dictionary as a context which surve dynamic data from `home()` function

---

And `redirect()` method used for after fulfilled request freshly redirect on specific url which passed in `redirect()` methods.

You cannot pass context in `redirect()` method.

### Ex -

```
def logout(request):
   return redirect('signin')
```

After successfully logged out redirect on `signin` url, `signin` url called `signin()` function which is render `signin.html` page

Comment: so we cannot redirect without having render() right?
And is it possible to redirect to external URL that is not in our app.

Like --
   return redirect('www.google.com')

Comment: You can redirect to any url without using render but  you have to understand the purpose of both render is used to club context in template and return a HttpResponse object while redirect is used for redirecting to some other page after some processing like form submission or login or sign up etc. When you use redirect url also changes and there status code of both the functions will be different like for redirect 301/302 is used.